# How to use update-alternatives to update my sage command

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, symlink

There is a `/usr/bin/sage` file in my PC, and I can use `sage` to launch **sage9.0** normally:
[image]

It is not a *soft link*, because `readlink /usr/bin/sage` return nothing, and  Now, I compiled a new version of **sage10.0** from the source code, and

```
#  ll /usr/bin/sage
```

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26791 Feb  8  2020 /usr/bin/sage*

I can use `/opt/sage-10.0/sage` to launch it:
[image]

Now I want to use `update-alternatives` to manage my two commands(`/usr/bin/sage`, `/opt/sage-10.0/sage`), but:

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/sage sage /opt/sage-10.0/sage 100
```

> warning: not replacing /usr/bin/sage with a link

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/sage sage /usr/bin/sage 200
```

> <link> and <path> can't be the same

How should I deal with these two errors?

Comment: in your case /usr/bin/sage is supposed to be a symlink, but it's not. Usually it's something like: `/usr/bin/prog -> /etc/alternatives/prog -> /path/to/prog-n`. And when you change it with `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/prog prog /path/to/prog-m 100`, it becomes `/usr/bin/prog -> /etc/alternatives/prog -> /path/to/prog-m`